# Raiserror not returning expected value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, raiseerror

I am using SQL Server and trying to return an error from a stored procedure to a caller. However it does not seem to work. When debugging the returned value is null.

Error handling:

```
begin try
    if not exists (select * from dbo.Employees where IsCEO = 1)
    begin
        insert into dbo.Employees (FirstName, LastName, Salary, IsCEO, IsManager, ManagerId, EmployeeRank)
        values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Salary, @IsCEO, @IsManager, @ManagerId, @EmployeeRank)              
    end
end try
begin catch
    return raiserror ('CEO already exists', 15, 1)
end catch
```

Comment: Acording to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) try block passes errors it gets to catch block. What oyu are doing here is saying if CEO doesn't exist, insert into Employees. If it CEO exists you do nothing, so there is no error te be caught.

Comment: `RETURN RAISERROR` doesn't make sense. `RETURN` *returns* an `int` value, not an error. Not to mention that you should really be using `THROW` now, rather than `RAISERROR`, as highlighted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Also, you error dosen't appear to match what you check. Your `IF` checks to see if the CEO **does not** exist, but then the error you attempt to raise states that it *does*.

Comment: `return raiserror ('CEO already exists', 15, 1)` is regarded as two statements. A `return` which exits the proc and then a `raiserror` that never executes

Comment: A great example of why properly terminating statements is so important, @MartinSmith , as that would be much more obvious if the statements were written (properly) as `RETURN; RAISERROR ('CEO already exists', 15, 1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you never encounter error in this code.

Logic of your code says if CEO doesn't exist, insert employee in the table. If it exists, do nothing. And then you check for errors in this and say CEO already exists which makes no sense.

Seem to me you wanted to do follwing.

```
begin try
if not exists (select * from dbo.Employees where IsCEO = 1)
begin
    insert into dbo.Employees (FirstName, LastName, Salary, IsCEO, IsManager, ManagerId, 
    EmployeeRank)
    values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Salary, @IsCEO, @IsManager, @ManagerId, 
    @EmployeeRank)              
end
ELSE
BEGIN
raiserror ('CEO already exists', 15, 1)
END
end try
begin catch
    --some code that handles possible errors in code above
end catch
```

Answer (score 3):

To repeat what I state in the comments, firstly your `RETURN` in the `CATCH` doesn't make sense. You don't *`RETURN`* an error, `RETURN` provides back an `int` value, and (historically) is used to denote the success of the procedure (`0` meaning success, anything else meaning failure). Their use, however, is somewhat more historical, especially now with things like `THROW` and `OUTPUT` parameters.

Speaking of `THROW`, you really should be using that too. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on `RAISERROR` states:

> > ##### Note
> >
> > The `RAISERROR` statement does not honor `SET XACT_ABORT`. New applications should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.

Finally, your error and your `IF` conflict. Your `IF` checks to see if a CEO **does not** exist, however, the error you raise states that they do.

I suspect therefore, you likely want something like like this, which doesn't need the `TRY...CATCH`, and just an `IF...ELSE`:

```sql
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Employees WHERE IsCEO = 1)
        INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (FirstName,
                                   LastName,
                                   Salary,
                                   IsCEO,
                                   IsManager,
                                   ManagerId,
                                   EmployeeRank)
        VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Salary, @IsCEO, @IsManager, @ManagerId, @EmployeeRank);
    ELSE
        THROW 50001, N'CEO does not exist', 16; --Use an error number (and state) appropriate for your environment
    --This will only be reached if the ELSE was not entered
    RETURN 0;
END;
```